# Como prefixar valor no input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Usei o Bootstrap para inserir um spam escrito http:// logo no começo do input.

Mas gostaria de saber como faço para deixar o input com esse valor por padrão, e depois o usuário só preenche o site que deseja.

```
<label for="name">SITE
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://</span>
        <input class="inp-contato" type="text" name="" id="" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="Digite seu site," value="value.site"/>
    </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com oque eu entendi em relação a sua pergunta, elaborei esse código veja se era isso que você queria.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.inp-contato').on('keypress',function(){
      if(this.value === ''){
          this.value = 'http://';
      }else if(this.value.indexOf('http://') === -1){
          this.value = 'http://';
      }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inp-contato" type="text" name="" id="" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" placeholder="Digite seu site" value=""/>
```

Comment: Eu acho que ele não quer que o valor apareça dentro do campo, afinal o mesmo já é exibido pelo boostrap que ele criou.

Comment: Entendo, posso não ter entendido direito, irei aguardar retorno dele.

Comment: Exato como disse o José, preciso enviar ele sem que apareça no campo. :/

Comment: Então precisa ser feito no momento do envio, você vai fazer esse envio via submit ou ajax, coloque mais informações.